# How to get the total number of mounted filesystems in Linux?

Tags: linux, mount

I know I can find out the list of mounted filesystems with command "mount", but I want to know how many mounted filesystems are there. Is it something related to the sort command? But I don't see a good command to do that. Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

use bellow command :

```
 $ mount |wc -l
```